# Tomcat Java Integration

Tags: java, tomcat, virtual-machine

I have encountered the following problem: After installing Eclpise with Java 10 as well as Tomcat 7.0, I get this error when running the server: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

I already tried to update Tomcat to the 9.0 version, which did not solve this issue either.

Does anyone know where this issue is rooted?

Comment: Is java globally installed or just for eclipse? Try `java -v` from the command line

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is globally installed.

Comment: How are you running the server? Command-line? IDE?

Comment: There's a 'Servers' tab in Eclipse. I right click the server and choose 'Start'.

Comment: Firstly, it starts running, however with the error message. After 45s I get a second message, saying that it needed to stop as there was no response after these 45s.

Comment: You need to check if your Tomcat's server configuration in Eclipse uses a valid JRE

Comment: I checked it and chose Java 10. Still get this error: "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start" (same for v7.0).

Comment: Try increasing the timeout maybe your server needs more that 45 sec. to start.